# Unable to store values in database through an Ajax request from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making an extension which takes the page url and store it in the database when the user submits the button.

I am stuck at this and i think that i am missing something in the extension part which I am unable to identify.
Its just a learning project so i haven't included any validations.

Here are a few details;

**manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Hello Extention",
"description": "POST details of the current page.",
"version": "0.1",
"content_scripts": [{
  "js": ["contentscript.js"],

}],
"web_accessible_resources": ["script.js"],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [

    "contextMenus",
    "bookmarks",
    "tabs", 
    "http://*/", 
    "https://*/"
]
}
```

**This is my popup.html**

```
  <input type="text" name="url" id="url" value=""><br>
  <input type="text" name="title" id="title"></br>
  <input type="button" name="submit" value="Go" id="submit"><br>
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
    var tabId = tab.id;
    var tabUrl = tab.url;
    var tabTitle = tab.title;

    document.getElementById("url").value = tabUrl;
    document.getElementById("title").value = tabTitle;

    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
        text: "10+"
    });
});
```

Now when user clicks on the go button i have called the ajax request

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
    document.getElementById("load").innerHTML = "<img style='height:30px;' src='/img/loading-  sprocket-gray-light-transparent.gif' />";
    var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (!xhr) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhr.open("post", "updatedata.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("url=" + url + "&title=" + title);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4) {
            reply = xhr.responseText;
            alert(reply);
        }
    }
});
```

**updatedata.php**

```
 <?php
    echo "welcome";
    include('connection.php');
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $title = $_GET['title'];
    mysql_query("insert into `data` VALUES('','$url','$title');" );
 ?>
```

Now the `alert(reply)` returns me the entire Updatedata.php file instead of sending the welcome message. I also tried executing the code separately (i.e. not from the extension) there its alerting me welcome and also inserting the values in the database. So I think there is nothing wrong with the Ajax request or the PHP file. but I think i am missing something  with the extention on how to send request or something

Comment: You cannot use PHP in a Chrome extension. Put it on a server and send the request to the server. And fix the glaring SQL injection vulnerability in your PHP script...

Comment: thanks for the reply.
you mean that it wont run on the localhost. Do i have to put it somewhere online?

Comment: It will only "run on localhost" if you start a PHP server on your local computer. Putting it "online" will also work. Though if you only want a locally accessible key-value store, use [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage). A full-fledged database is also available in the form of [`IndexedDB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), but given your level of knowledge, I would not even try to use it (no offence intended).

Comment: @RobW Would you consider compiling an answer out of your advice, so this question can be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use PHP in a Chrome extension. Put it on a PHP server and send the request to the server. And fix the glaring SQL injection vulnerability in your PHP script.

Your PHP script seems to only be used for storing data in a database. Unless you need to access this data through a different view, I suggest to use the client-side storage APIs to persist data, e.g. with [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

If you need a full-fledged database, take a look at the [`IndexedDB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API). Given your level of knowledge, I suggest to use the `chrome.storage` API because it is easier to use, especially for novice programmers (no offence intended)

Comment: Thanks..also it was just for learning purpose, so i haven't included the vulnerability checks. And once Thanks for your suggestion about the chrome.storage.

Comment: hello rob, i have put my file on the php server..but the values of the  `$_GET['url']` and `$_POST['title']` is showing empty... and null values are getting inserted into the database..anyidea?

Comment: Your method of uploading data is broken. I suggest to use jQuery.ajax since you've already used jQuery in your extension, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax